# Border-bottom not moving up in container

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to add a border-bottom and shift it upwards, but I haven't been able to accomplish this, even with line-height, margin-bottom, and padding-bottom.

What I want it to look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOAjX.png

What it looks like now (red for visuals):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/poNMP.png

HTML:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8fJq.png

Parent Container:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkD0E.png

Search Field Container:
[Div]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUdLf.png

CSS

```
.search_panel_base_list {

    
    .search_panel_header {
        background-color: #F2F2F2;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

        #navbar_container {
           line-height: 1;
        }
     
        #search_container {
            width: 90%;
            align-self: center;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;   
            border-width: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid red;
            line-height: 20px; 

    
            .search_icon {   
                display: flex;
                justify-content: flex-end;
                // padding-right: 35px;
                height:20px;
               
            }
            .search_box {
                #search_text_input {
                
                    border-width: 4px;
                    border-radius: 4px;
                    height: 40px;
                    border: none;
                    font-size:12px;
                    // padding: 8px 34px 8px 20px;
                    min-height: unset;                
    
                    ::placeholder {
                        color: #58595B;
                    }
                }  
            }
        }
        #search_filter_header {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 20px 25px 0px 25px;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 16px;
            color: #58595B;
            .search_results_filter {
                display: flex;
                width: 75px;
                justify-content: space-around;
            }
        }
    }
    
}

.ui_screen {
    position: static;
}

.input {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#after_list_container {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
} 

#search_container_container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Not sure how much this will help, but here's how the HTML is generated.

```
SearchPanel.prototype.setupSearchField = function () {
        var self = this;


        var aStructure = {
            style: 'search_panel_header ui_screen panel popup',
            children: [
                {id: 'navbar_container', style: 'notch_top_padding'},
                {
                    id: 'search_container_container', children: [
                    {id: 'search_container',
                    children: [
                        {style: 'search_box', interior: HGEN.input({style: 'input search_text', id: 'search_text_input', placeholder: 'Search'})},
                        {style: 'search_icon', interior: HGEN.image({src: Resources.resources.ICON_SEARCH.src})}
                    ]}]
                },
                {
                    id: 'search_filter_header',
                    children: [
                        {
                            style: 'search_results_header',
                            interior: CrowdHub_App.LANG.SEARCH_RESULTS
                        },
                        {
                            style: 'search_results_filter',
                            interior:
                                CrowdHub_App.LANG.SEARCH_FILTER + HTMLGenerator_getImage({style: 'filter_logo', src: Resources.resources.ICON_FILTERS.src})
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        };
var struct = $(HGEN.tree(aStructure));
self.mDiv.find('#before_list_container').append(struct);
```

Let me know any thoughts are question, thank you!

Comment: You can create a snippet in which we can run your code. Look for the `<>` icon when editing your post. It will make helping you out way easier.

Comment: I wish I could post all of my code, but the way HTML is generated is super weird through my company so it would need multiple files.

Comment: @WillCrawford we don't need the whole 'HTML' just the container `div` it would be helpful when applying classes

Answer (score 0):

add a border to the .search_box instead of #search_text_input

```
.search_box {
                border-bottom: 4px solid #DADADA;
                border-radius: 4px;
                padding: 8px 34px 8px 20px;                
                }
```

Comment: The search box is just the input field and placeholder text,
see image: https://i.imgur.com/2yHakOr.png

Comment: post the HTML and CSS here please so I can help you better

Comment: Posted it up top, hopefully can be helpful

Comment: please paste HTML here

Comment: Add a fixed width to .search_box and  width of 100%  for #search_text_input